# Scanning values from file using fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

Hey I need to read the data from file and print it(i have to use fscanf). My code only works for first value when I add more it's not working.
Here is my code

```
char name[5];    //this value is fixed size
char isWorking;
double latitude;  //the length may vary
double longitude; //the length may vary
while(fscanf(fp2,"%s %c %lf %lf",name,isWorking,latitude,longitude) == 4)  {
 printf("\n%s %c %lf %lf",id,type,latitude,longitude);
 i++;
 }
```

my file looks like that

> ```
> Bob1 Y 122.232323 -9.323232
> Bob2 N 9.0001 -9.001
> ```

It doesn't print anything except when I remove other values and try to read only name

Comment: Your compiler should have warned about this.  Save yourself time.  Enable all warnings or get a new compiler.

Comment: You had better to eliminate the spaces in the format string, as in "%s%c%lf%lf", so you are free of using tabs or newlines between the fields.